# Eigen taking a block of block

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a large vector and I need to have access to it's parts as to separate vectors. For simplicity suppose that there is a vector A of length 10. Vector B is it's first five elements. Vector C is the first 3 elements of B. B and C share memory with A.

Eigen has several classes to handle such situation. `Ref`, `Map` and `Block`. Which one is the most natural way to handle the situation above? Also I'm specifically interested in case when B and C are created from A during their construction (to be able to build B and C inside member initialiser list of a class).

Seems that `Block` is the solution here. But `Block`s can't be created from other `Block`s...

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"

int main()
{
  Eigen::VectorXd a(10);
  Eigen::VectorBlock<Eigen::VectorXd> b(a, 0, 5);
  Eigen::VectorBlock<Eigen::VectorXd> c(b, 0, 3);
  return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'Eigen::VectorBlock<Eigen::VectorXd>' (aka
      'VectorBlock<Matrix<double, Dynamic, 1> >')
  Eigen::VectorBlock<Eigen::VectorXd> c(b, 0, 3);
                                      ^ ~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rare case where `auto` is well suited for Eigen:

```
auto b = a.segment(0,5);
auto c = b.segment(0,3);
```

The type of `c` will be nested `Block`, i.e., `Block<Block<VectorXd,...>, ...>`.
In this case, `Ref` will work too:

```
Ref<VectorXd> b = a.segment(0,5);
Ref<VectorXd> c = b.segment(0,3);
```

This might even be better because a `Ref<VectorXd>` is simpler to optimize for the compiler than a `Block<Block<>>`.

Answer (score -2):

I just want to put my two cents in on this, because this can be done without using auto or Ref or Map. Here is some working code, which can easily be adapted to .segment(i,N) *if you want* but this code does exactly what the question wants using the Vector method .head(N):

```
  VectorXd setA;
  VectorXd subsetB;
  VectorXd subsetC;
  setA = VectorXd::Random(10, 1);
  cout << "New" <<endl;
  subsetB = setA.head(5);
  subsetC = subsetB.head(3);
  cout << setA.transpose() << endl;
  cout << "Sub B" << endl;
  cout << subsetB.transpose() << endl;
  cout << "Sub C " << endl;
  cout << subsetC.transpose() << endl;
```

This is my output:

```
New
 -0.999984  -0.736924   0.511211 -0.0826997  0.0655345  -0.562082  -0.905911   0.357729   0.358593   0.869386
Sub B
 -0.999984  -0.736924   0.511211 -0.0826997  0.0655345
Sub C 
-0.999984 -0.736924  0.511211
```

This are my includes:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
```

And using:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
```

Comment: in this case vectors do not share memory

Comment: Why couldn't you just initialize them differently? Then they would and the code would still work.  VectorXd subsetB = setA.head(5);
  VectorXd subsetC = subsetB.head(3);